# Remove NA in 3D array and reshape

Tags: arrays, r, na

I have an array `num [1:800, 1:533, 1:3]`. Essentially an image with 800 columns, 533 rows and 3 channels. In every row of every channel, there is exactly one NA.

How can I remove all NA's in all three channels and reshape the array to have one column less and therefore an array with `num [1:799, 1:533, 1:3]` dimensions?

I tried `na.omit()` but it did not work.

Example:

```
testarray<- array(c(1:27), c(3,3,3))
testarray[1,1,] = NA
testarray[2,2,] = NA
testarray[3,1,] = NA

> testarray
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA    4    7
[2,]    2   NA    8
[3,]   NA    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   13   16
[2,]   11   NA   17
[3,]   NA   15   18

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   22   25
[2,]   20   NA   26
[3,]   NA   24   27
```

This array has exactly one NA for every row and every channel.
I want to remove the NA's and reshape the array to get the following output:

```
, , 1
     [,1] [,2] 
[1,]    4    7
[2,]    2    8
[3,]    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] 
[1,]   13   16
[2,]   11   17
[3,]   15   18

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] 
[1,]   22   25
[2,]   20   26
[3,]   24   27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `na.omit` with `apply` and transpose with `aperm`.

**Example**

Consider array `A`.

```
A
# , , 1
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3   NA
# [2,]   NA    4    6
# 
# , , 2
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3   NA
# [2,]   NA    4    6
# 
# , , 3
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   NA    5
# [2,]   NA    4    6
# 
# , , 4
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   NA    5
# [2,]    2   NA    6
```

*Method*

```
aperm(apply(A, c(1, 3), na.omit), c(2, 1, 3))
# , , 1
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    4    6
# 
# , , 2
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    4    6
# 
# , , 3
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    5
# [2,]    4    6
# 
# , , 4
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    5
# [2,]    2    6
```

***Data***

```
A <- structure(c(1L, NA, 3L, 4L, NA, 6L, 1L, NA, 3L, 4L, NA, 6L, 1L, 
NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 5L, 6L), .Dim = 2:4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to work for the example. When I try to use it for my 800x533x3 image I get an error. `Error in aperm.default(apply(seam_img, c(1, 3), na.omit), c(2, 1, 3)) : 
  'perm' is of wrong length 3 (!= 2)`.

Comment: @ViktorG Does `any(apply(A, c(1, 3), function(x) sum(is.na(x))) != 1)` applied to your image yield `TRUE`?

Comment: Ok, this indicates that min. one row of your array has more than just one `NA`. Can you confirm that? What shall happen in this case?

Comment: Ok that is a problem... That should not happen. I suppose that I made a mistake somewhere else. I will accept this answer as the correct one. Would it be ok if I commented here if further questions appear?

Comment: @ViktorG Sure, no problem!